# How can I take flat rows of relational data and put these into a C# class?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an application that is using Entity Framework however it is my understanding that the latest Entity Framework can still not join tables if the join is not on the Primary Key.

So for this reason I have C# code that calls a stored procedure that joins some tables and returns my data. Here is a simplified version of my problem.

I have a relational database that is returning question data. If there is one question that has five answers then there will be five rows returned and each row will have the same question information.

Here is the class that the data is going into:

```
public partial class Result1
{
   public Guid QuestionUId { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public int AnswerId { get; set; }
   public string AnswerText { get; set; } 
}
```

What I need is to take this relational data and create a collection of the Question class:

```
public partial class Question
{
   public Guid QuestionUId { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public string Answer { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

}

public partial class Answer 
{
   public int AnswerId { get; set; }
   public string AnswerText { get; set; } 
}
```

Can someone give me some ideas how I can get the data and fit it into the Question class so that the Answers field is also populated correctly?

Here's what I have so far:

```
 var sql = @"dbo.sp_get_questions @UserId,        
                                  @UserTestId;";
        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
                    {
                        new SqlParameter("@UserId", Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId())),
                        new SqlParameter("@UserTestId", userTestId)
                    };
        try
        {
            var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<Result1>(sql, parameters);
            var questions1 = await query.ToListAsync();
            var questions2 = questions1
            .Select((t, index) => new
```

The problem is I have just no idea how to do the .Select or even if I am taking the right approach.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: It's not that EF requires foreign keys to do joins.  It just doesn't create navigation properties if there isn't a foreign key.  But you should ask yourself why are you doing a join that doesn't involve a foreign key in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not happy with how EF joins, you may still create your own. I am not sure on how your data is structured but you could write something like:

```
context.Questions
.GroupJoin
(
    context.Answers,
    x=>x.Id, // this is the pk on Questions
    x=>x.QuestionId //this is the fk on Answers
    (q,a)=>new Question
    {
        q.QuestionUId,
        q.Text,
        Answers = a.Select(an=>new Answer{an.AnswerId,an.AnswerText})
    }    
)
```

This will result on a set of questions where each question has a set of answers.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  However will this not result in a large number of rows being returned from the database?

Comment: You may always add a Where clause on your query in order to limit the rows returned.